# Zeppelin sprawls multiple JAVA processes

Tags: java, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

I currently have the latest zeppelin source running in a master server with HDP 2.5, I have also a worker server.

Under the master server, I detected several JAVA processes being generated in the last 12 days, which they did not finish and were consuming memory. At one point the memory got full and was not able to run Zeppelin under its Yarn queue. I have a queue system in Yarn, one for JobServer and another for Zeppelin. Zeppelin is currently running with root but will change to each own service account. System is CENTOS 7.2

The log shows the following processes, for ease of reading I started to differentiate them:
Process 1 to 3 seem to be zeppelin, I don't know what process 4 and 5 are.
Question here is: Is there a config issue? Why is zeppelin-daemon not killing this JAVA processes? What could be a fix for avoiding this issues?

```html
<p><strong>PROCESS #1</strong>
/usr/java/default/bin/java 
-Dhdp.version=2.4.2.0-258 
-cp /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/local-repo/2BXMTZ239/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/lib/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/classes/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/test-classes/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-zengine/target/test-classes/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
:/usr/hdp/current/spark-thriftserver/conf/:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
:/etc/hadoop/conf/ 
-Xms1g 
-Xmx1g 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dzeppelin.log.file=/var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter-spark-root-cool-server-name1.log org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=::/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/local-repo/2BXMTZ239/*:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/*:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/lib/*
:
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/test-classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-zengine/target/test-classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions= 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dzeppelin.log.file=/var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter-spark-root-cool-server-name1.log 
--class org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer 
/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 44001

</p><p><strong>PROCESS #2 </strong>
/usr/java/default/bin/java -Dhdp.version=2.4.2.0-258 
-cp /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/local-repo/2BXMTZ239/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/lib/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/classes/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/test-classes/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-zengine/target/test-classes/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
:/usr/hdp/current/spark-thriftserver/conf/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
:/etc/hadoop/conf/ 
-Xms1g 
-Xmx1g 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dzeppelin.log.file=/var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter-spark-root-cool-server-name1.log 
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit 
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=
:
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/local-repo/2BXMTZ239/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/lib/*
:
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/test-classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-zengine/target/test-classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions= 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dzeppelin.log.file=/var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter-spark-root-cool-server-name1.log 
--class org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer 
/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
40641

</p><p><strong>PROCESS #3</strong>
/usr/java/default/bin/java 
-Dhdp.version=2.4.2.0-258 
-cp /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/local-repo/2BXMTZ239/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/lib/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/classes/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/test-classes/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-zengine/target/test-classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
:/usr/hdp/current/spark-thriftserver/conf/
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
:/etc/hadoop/conf/ 
-Xms1g 
-Xmx1g 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dzeppelin.log.file=/var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter-spark-root-cool-server-name1.log 
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit 
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=::/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/local-repo/2BXMTZ239/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/lib/*
:
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/test-classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-zengine/target/test-classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions= 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dzeppelin.log.file=/var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter-spark-root-cool-server-name1.log 
--class org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.10-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 60887

</p><p><strong>PROCESS #4</strong>
/usr/java/default/bin/java 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dzeppelin.log.file=/var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter-cassandra-root-cool-server-name1.log 
-Xms1024m 
-Xmx1024m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-cp ::/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/cassandra/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/lib/*
:
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/test-classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-zengine/target/test-classes org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer

</p><p><strong>PROCESS #5</strong>
/usr/java/default/bin/java 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dzeppelin.log.file=/var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter-cassandra-root-cool-server-name1.log 
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-cp ::/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/interpreter/cassandra/*
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/lib/*
::/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/test-classes
:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zeppelin/zeppelin-zengine/target/test-classes org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Apache Zeppelin** uses [multi-process architecture](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/development/writingzeppelininterpreter.html), where each interpreter is running as at least one separate JVM process, communicating to ZeppelinServer though Apache Thrift protocol.

[image: zeppelin interpreter architecure]

4 and 5 in your case looks like a Cassandra interpreter processes.

You can always shutdown\restart them from Zeppelin UI in Interpreters menu. Check out more about this and other intepreter-related features at [Zeppelin official docs](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/manual/interpreters.html)

Comment: Great answer, 2 questions on this: when I stop the zeppelin processes I notice the interpreter processes are still running, why? Should I only use the Zeppelin UI to shut them down? Why the script does not shuts them down? I an running .\zeppelin-daemon stop
why the cassandra interpreter would spawn more than 1 process if it is 1 interpreter?